# Running a script requiring root as a non-root user?

Tags: java, linux, docker, ssl, opensuse

**Current situation**

I have a base docker image (built on opensuse) that other images are built upon.

The base image runs some startup scripts at runtime.

One of the commands the startup scripts runs is this:

```
update-ca-certificates
```

[https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html#:~:text=update%2Dca%2Dcertificates%20is%20a,%2Fetc%2Fca%2Dcertificates](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html#:%7E:text=update%2Dca%2Dcertificates%20is%20a,%2Fetc%2Fca%2Dcertificates).

`update-ca-certificates` writes to the following directory, which is owned by root:

```
/var/lib/ca-certificates
```

`update-ca-certificates` also calls `chmod` on the directory, as as `chmod` can only be run as the owner of the dir, this implies `update-ca-certificates` must be run as root:

https://github.com/p11-glue/p11-kit/blob/master/trust/save.c#L614

**Requirements**

1. The startup scripts executed by the container at runtime should be able to run as an arbitrary, non-root user.
2. This arbitrary, non-root user should be able to be provided by the `USER` directive in the dockerfile or the `--user=xxx:yyy` flag passed to `docker run`

**Whats been tried**

**Option 1: sudo**

The first thing tried was Introducing a limited number of commands that any user can run with sudo to the base image which will allow the startup scripts to be run by non-root users.

For example, adding the following file to /etc/sudoers.d:

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates
```

then updating the startup script to add sudo to the command:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Problem with option 1:

sudo checks the passwd file to resolve the uid to a username for permissions checking, so the user needs to exist on the container first. This option does not work with anonymous users or domain users as they won't exist in the passwd file. The following error is seen:

```
sudo: unknown uid xxx: who are you?
```

**Option 2: setuid**

The setuid permission bit tells Linux to run a program with the effective user id of the owner (root) instead of the executor.

If we run the `/usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates` with the setuid flag, it may work. Something like:

```
chmod u+s /usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates
/usr/sbin/update-ca-certificates
```

Problem with option 2:

setuid only applies to executables, shell scripts (such as `update-ca-certificates`) ignore the setuid bit.

We could wrap the `update-ca-certificates` in a binary as described here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369

However, as the comments on the above post state, this may be an insecure approach.

**Option 3: Temporarily opening up the permissions on the `/var/lib/ca-certificates` dir**

The next thing tried was to open up the permissions (temporarily) on the `/var/lib/ca-certificates` dir, so that any user could write to them. Something like:

```
RUN chmod -R ugo+rwx /var/lib/ca-certificates
```

Problem with option 3:

Option 3 only works up to the point at which `update-ca-certificates` calls `chmod` on the directory:

https://github.com/p11-glue/p11-kit/blob/master/trust/save.c#L614

As `chmod` can only be run by the owner of the dir (root), the following error is seen:

```
p11-kit: couldn't set directory permissions: /var/lib/ca-certificates/openssl: Operation not permitted
```

**Option 4: Temporarily changing the owner of `/var/lib/ca-certificates` dir**

Following on from the problem with option 3, I wanted to see if it was possible to temporarily change the owner of the `/var/lib/ca-certificates` dir.

However, I don't think this is possible, given that the arbitrary, non-root user would not be known to the base image at build time:

```
RUN sudo chown -R <DON'T KNOW THE USER YET?> /var/lib/ca-certificates
```

Comment: Usually the base TLS certificate set doesn't change that frequently; can you run `update-ca-certificates` in your image's Dockerfile instead, avoiding this problem?

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't think so. The startup script does more than just `update-ca-certificates`, it first copies certs into /etc/pki/trust/anchors. The certs it copies can be provided by a derived image at runtime.